# How to add zoom in and zoom out buttons in Nattable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

There is way to zoom in and zoom out in Nattable 2.0 onwards.

(http://blog.vogella.com/2020/03/05/nattable-dynamic-scaling-enhancements/)

But how to make this functionality work on button clicks similar to browser.

[Expected zoom in and zoom out view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvW7J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post says:

> The dynamic scaling can be triggered programmatically by executing the
> ConfigureScalingCommand on the NatTable instance.

So you need to implement such buttons in your UI that execute the `ConfigureScalingCommand` with the according parameters.

Comment: Thanks for information. It works fine for font/text only . How to scale all cell painters programmatically? Tried to register - natTable.registerCommandHandler(new CSSConfigureScalingCommandHandler(natTable)); However it dint work for me. any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Are you using CSS styling in NatTable?

Comment: No. we are not using CSS styling.

Comment: Why do you then think your approach would work? The blog post explains what needs to be done. The cell painters with images need to be registered and handled in a way that respects scaling.

Comment: To be more precise, it is the first option of three that registers the `ScalingUiBindingConfiguration`